# Bootstrap grid alignment issue in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

Building a site in firefox now that displays three items aligned next to one another.

Each `div` is `col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4` respectively but Firefox is breaking the row into two lines where as Chrome isn't.

Current version of Firefox. Not sure what the hell is going on. So any help would be appreciated.

### Firefox

[image]

### Chrome

[image]

### Code

Note that page-main is just a wrapper.

```
<div class="page-main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row center">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are these `page-main` and `center` classes? Those aren't part of Bootstrap and could potentially be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and it works...

[image]

Try this link...
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7366/embedded/result/

SO says I need to post code with jsfiddle links, so ignore this..

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Happy now?!");
```

Comment: Yea I'm an idiot totally overlooked I had a mess of old project code getting in the way. I've since scrapped and started fresh. Thanks for bringing back the sanity.